# Properly unbind service from activity

Tags: android, android-service-binding

I have a simple android app with an activity that binds a service. The basic code is like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyService service;
    private boolean serviceIsBound;

    private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            service = ((MyService.LocalBinder) binder).getService();
            serviceIsBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            serviceIsBound = false;
        }
    };
    
    // Service gets bound via intent in onCreate()

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (serviceIsBound) {
            service.unbindService(serviceConnection);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered` in the call `service.unbindService(...)` when I close the activity.

I tried `onStop()` instead of `onDestroy()` --> same error.
I tried removing the `onDestroy()` --> I get an error `android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked`. This error of course makes sense -- after all you should clean up your service connections. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `unbindService()` on the same `Context` that you call `bindService()` on. Presumably, given the structure of your sample, you are calling `bindService()` on the `MyActivity` instance; if so, call `unbindService()` on that `MyActivity` instance as well.

---

Note that you probably should not be doing it this way. On a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation), your `MyActivity` instance will be destroyed and recreated. This means that you will unbind from the service, then bind to it again. If nothing else is bound to that service, and that service is not started, the service will be destroyed (when it is unbound) and then recreated (when the new activity instance binds again).

It is *very* likely that you do not need a bound service, particularly if the service is in the same process as the rest of your app. If you are certain that you need a bound service, bind and unbind from something that survives configuration changes, such as an `AndroidViewModel`. There, you would use the `Application` as your `Context` for the bind/unbind calls. Or, if you are using a dependency inversion (DI) framework (e.g., Dagger/Hilt, Koin), you might get a `Context` from it. Or, if appropriate, bind and unbind from some DI-managed singleton, again using the `Application` as your `Context.

FWIW, [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/EmbedServer) contains a bound service. It is used by [this client app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/EmbedClient), which binds and unbinds from a `ViewModel`.